# detect anomaly in time series

Tags: signal-processing, time-series

I have data on 5 agriculture fields over the same period of time. At some point, there is a sudden change in behavior for all 5 time series,  which correspond to the harvest of the field. My task is to implement a methodology to determine the date at which the field was
harvested and provide prediction intervals. 
Here is what it looks like [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLums.png). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bDqu.png) is the correlation matrix.

As you can see, it's not obvious from visual inspection as there are several peaks and ups and downs .
It's important to say that I don't know what the values in the time series correspond to.

I have though of some methods like max(sum over all TS of the derivatives at each point), or using first and second derivative etc. But I want to know if there is a more systematic way or method? And how to provide prediction intervals.

I know that there are a lot of packages in R to work with Time series (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139660/detecting-changes-in-time-series-r-example) but I have to use python for this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to know the relations between the various fields, for instance, are they orthogonal component of the same vector field? In that case, looking a the norm $\sqrt{f_1^2+f_2^2+f_3^2}$ may be useful

Comment: Also, +1 for using Python and not R

Comment: thanks @Federico. I've added the correlation matrix. Then what do you once you have the relations and the norm you mentioned. How do you go to find that date?

Comment: Uhm... I'm starting to wonder whether you mean [crop fields](https://www.google.fr/search?q=crop+field&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQk4Gw_JXfAhUIWhoKHeNZBUkQ_AUIDigB&biw=1600&bih=801) while I'm thinking of [vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field)...

Comment: In that case my previous suggestion is not very meaningful

Comment: IMHO, at least one time series related to one field such that you know the date of harvest is **fundamental** for solving such problem.

Comment: @Federico Yes :) I meant crop fields.

Comment: Indeed, without any additional information, even if you are able to find anomalies, then you can not conclude that anomalies correspond to harvest date. The framework you are working in is [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning)

Comment: @the_candyman exactly. That's why I have to provide prediction intervals. So you suggest to run something like k-means on that? but defining clusters doesn't help for the harvest date. hmm maybe some unsupervised anomaly detection method like Autoencoders is good. But I have little data (only 30 samples)

Comment: You have some context you can leverage to inform your estimation processes: possible harvest dates.  No crop that I can think of is harvested in winter or spring. So you can declare half of your data as "no harvest possible" and the other half as "harvest possible".  Which half depends on Northern or Southern Hemisphere.